# Using Sass-Bootstrap with Rails 4 is compiling really slow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, precompile

I'm new to Rails and I'm using the sass-bootstrap gem to use bootstrap in my Rails project. Everything was loading reasonably fast, but now everytime I change any scss file the precompile time takes up to 90 seconds to complete.

In the application.css.scss I'm importing bootstrap at the top and requiring partials base on other suggestions, and have set the config.assets.debug to false;

Here's my application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
*= require _static_pages
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
 */
```

Is there anything else that I may not be doing right that is causing such painful loadtimes?
I've seen other SO questions similar but none seem to quite fit my situation with Bootstrap or provide an answer that works.

Comment: You shouldn't need `require_self`.  Rails will include the contents of the manifest file automatically at the end of the manifest.  Also, you don't seem to have any CSS in this file (so two reasons you shouldn't need it).  Also, where is `_static_pages` located?  Just be sure you are not already including that with the `require_tree .` directive.

Comment: I took out the require. Actually when I take out the static pages it's not included, but I think it should be it's in the same directory as application.scss so shouldn't the `require_tree .` include it?

Comment: Yes it should if it is in the same folder.  What is the actual file name (with extensions)?  Do you have folders within that folder?  If you are still seeing slow load times, you can try requiring each file explicitly here and then figure out by process of elimination which file is driving your load times.

Comment: Right now I only have the static pages css and bootstrap. They are both in the same app/assets/stylesheets/ directory as application.scss. I have application.scss and static_pages.scss. I'm importing bootstrap from the bootstrap gem that I installed. I'm fairly certain the slow load times are coming from bootstrap in some way being it is significantly bigger than my static_pages.scss which is only about 30 lines right now.

Comment: I would take everything out of the manifest file, make sure there are still not delays, then add in the two files manually one at a time if you want to understand what is happening.  As I mentioned, your file extensions may be an issue with the static pages file.  Also, keep in mind that there are three separate areas Rails will check for assets (`app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets`).